# suppose r,s in R

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $r,s$ in $\mathbb R$. prove that:

a) $r \in \mathbb Q$ and $(r+s) \notin \mathbb Q \Rightarrow s \notin \mathbb Q$

b) $r \notin \mathbb Q,\; s \neq 0,\; rs \in \mathbb Q \Rightarrow s \notin \mathbb Q$

My proof:

a) Suppose $s$ is in $\mathbb Q$ so that $s = \frac cd$ 
and $r = \frac ab$ 
so that $r + s = a/b + c/d = (ad + bc)/bd  \in \mathbb Q$ 
which is contrary to what is given. 
So $s$ is not in $\mathbb Q$

b) Once again suppose $s$ in $\mathbb Q$, and $s = \frac cd$ 
then since $rs$ is in $\mathbb Q$ then $rs = m/n$ 
and $r = m/(ns) = md/nc$ 
which implies $r$ is in $\mathbb Q$ contrary to what is given 
So that $s$ is not in $\mathbb Q$

Is this right?